# Backup /data/system/xxxx.bin to /sdcard

Tags: android, file, backup, sd-card

I'm fairly new to apk development. So far, after a book purchase and with a lot of Googling I've managed to make an application that controls some features of my custom ROM. I'm currently trying to implement 2 backup features. I want to backup /data/system/batterystats.bin to /sdcard and also i want to backup launcher.db of my touchwiz launcher to /sdcard.

For the first part i haven't actually found anything. I've searched a lot about how to restore a file, not much has come up. It's mostly about SQL .db files. I've also looked for the possibility to run a shell script via the apk just to perform this backup. With a shell script it's easy work, but doing this via .java, i honestly have no clue.

Also, i've tried quite a lot of code to get my sqlite database file to backup, but i was quite unsuccessful. Here's my code for you to look at:

```
public class Backup extends Activity {
public void exportDB(){
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "data/data/com.sec.android.app.twlauncher/databases/launcher.db";
            String backupDBPath = sd + "/launcher.db";
            File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I have added permissions for external storage write, of course in the androidmanifest, but nothing happens. No FC, it just sits there doing nothing. And when I check my sdcard, there's nothing there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: look at the logcat output. there might be a "fileNotFoundException". Without further testing I think the file you want to copy does not exist or the file you want to write to is not yet created.

Comment: it probably doesn't force close because the error occurs within the try-statement and is catched. For better Error handling it is easier to use `catch (FileNotFoundException e) and catch(IOException e)` and that stuff instead of a generic `catch (Exception e)`.

Comment: thank you so much for your replies. i will try some further testing. do you happen to know anything about the first part of my question? backing up files (non SQLlite) like /data/system/batterstats.bin to sdcard, or even better yet (for me :P) how to run a shell script command via the apk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [RootTools](http://code.google.com/p/roottools/) (the jar file).

You can then run linux commands like this:

`RootTools.sendShell(command);`

For example to backup, you could do:

```
RootTools.sendShell("cp -f /data/data/com.sec.android.app.twlauncher/databases/launcher.db /sdcard/directory/");
```

And to restore the file:

```
RootTools.sendShell("cp -f /sdcard/directory/launcher.db /data/data/com.sec.android.app.twlauncher/databases/");
```

cp is the copy command, and -f is what allows it to overwite the file if it already exists.

RootTools are great, and for the commands, just google how to do linux commands and then place them into the `sendShell`

I have no idea how to do it with java. I personally think that using the linux commands are 10 times easier, though.

And to note, it is actually good to get sdcard location like this:
`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`

and then append the rest of the storage location info to the end of that.

Comment: thank you so much. you saved me TONS of time. and yes i find shell scripts a million times simpler than java as well. i was looking at root tools yesterday, didn't know about the sendShell command however! it works :D

Comment: You're welcome. I was amazed and so happy when I found out about roottools. The jar file contains HTML files that index the commands. The documentation is moderate, but the Wiki also has some useful info.